# Autologon on Windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, authentication, automatic-logon

I have several computers in my enterprise with autologin enabled.

But, in one computer, this option does not work.

I try this :

www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10 (method 1 and 2)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon.aspx
Export key registry from another computer where it works and import it

The result is :
Computer start and ask mail address
The username change on [logon page](http://postimg.org/image/s84zg49p7/)

In the eventvwr, only this message relating to authentication :

"Microsoft Windows Server has detected that NTLM authentication is presently being used between clients and this server."

But, this is not a server, just a client computer belonging to domain

The computer work on Windows 10 x64 (windows is activated)
Of course, the credential and connectivity are valid

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Edit : 

Thank for your reply,
I already configured in [normal account](http://postimg.org/image/vg1g7dtoj/)

Comment: Hi! I reinstall Windows completely -> Join to domain ->Test -> It's Work / Update to build 10240 -> Don't autologin after update...

Comment: After this update, Autologon work only if : Computer not in the domain or network card is disconnect (but computer into the domain)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to disable Microsoft Account and enable "normal" account.

"Configuration" > "Accounts" > "Login with local account instead".

You will be asked about microsoft account password.

Comment: I have more then 3 systems all configured to use a connected account all configured to automatically log into that account.  A local account isn't required

Answer (score 0):

You can do this editing the registry. Here is the process:

1. Win + R and type Regedit
2. We go to Winlogon:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   |
   |------Software
       |
       |------Microsoft
           |
           |-----------WindowsNT
               |
               |-----------Current
                   |
                   |-WinLogon
   ```
3. Here we create three chainvalues:

   ```
   DefaultPassword->User Password
   DefaultUserName-> user
   AutoAdminLogon-> 1
   ```

Comment: Methode 2 of www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10, already tested :(

[View my config](http://postimg.org/image/x8azgbyjf/)

The account password is very simple, only use in internal enterprise, but I test with more sophisticated password