# Autologin Windows 10 20H2

Tags: windows-10, auto-login, autologon

I have a Windows 10 Pro (32 Bit Version 20H2 Build 19042.789 Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0) computer that runs a weather station and uploads data to several sites.   To assure data is uploaded I had the system set to autologin a user in the event of a reboot.

After recent Windows Update, the autologin no longer works.

I have found a few posts elsewhere reporting the issue after a recent update but solutions all are for earlier versions.

I have seen [Autologin Windows 10 not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1128341/autologon-on-windows-10-not-working) but hope this can be accomplished without adding the user name and password in plain text in registry.  I have not tested this as the post is from 2016

[Autologon on Windows 10 not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1128341/autologon-on-windows-10-not-working)

[image: User Account Screen pre update]

The checkbox "Users must enter a user name etc." does not appear.  However, another system with exact same OS build other than being 64 bit does display the checkbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Additional searching  found this link [Users Must Enter a User Name and Password to Use This Computer” Checkbox Missing in Windows 10](https://www.askvg.com/fix-users-must-enter-a-user-name-and-password-to-use-this-computer-checkbox-missing-in-windows-10/)  Unsure what was different about my search but it was "Users Must Enter a User Name and Password to Use This Computer” Checkbox Missing which I have used before.

The first option was missing from my Windows install.

The registry fix worked.  Thanks to author at askvg.com

1. Press WIN+R keys together to launch RUN dialog box. Now type regedit and press Enter. It’ll open Registry Editor.
2. Now go to following key:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device
3. Double-click on DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion and change its value to 0
4. Open “control userpasswords2” or “netplwiz” programs and you’ll get “Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer” checkbox back.

NOTE: If the checkbox doesn’t appear after editing Registry, restart your computer and it’ll appear now.

Tested and working.

Comment: Facing the same issue on a system. Registry way not working

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me.